# Automatically link filenames with Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm interested in switching to the Atom text editor, but one thing that's keeping me with Vim is vim-notes, a plugin that automatically highlights names of your notes and allows you to jump to them by positioning your cursor over them and pressing `gf` (go to file under cursor). Is there a way to make Atom:

1. Read all the filenames in my ~/Notes directory
2. Highlight or underline any text in any .note file that's the name of a file in the ~/Notes directory, even if that note title has spaces.
3. Allow me to jump to the highlighted note by pressing some kind of key combination while the cursor is over it

I don't think there's a plugin for this, but if it's possible, I might be able to make one.

Comment: I just searched Atom open file under cursor and found this https://atom.io/packages/open-this

Comment: That's awesome. But is there a way to have it highlight files that exist in a certain directory?